# How has <IMG> element and it's containing <DIV> moved (Left, Top) without also moving/taking its SRC (Google Maps Marker)

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-maps-api-3, marker

I really hope this is a case of can't see the wood for the trees, because I just can't believe my own eyes at the moment! If you look at the image below you'll see my mouse pointer is hovering over a an IMG tag in the Chrome Debugger/Inspect Elements tab, and the handy tool-tip in the mobile display is usefully showing "img 45 x 40" exactly where my hg.png image ***should*** be rendering. Yet Hansel and Gretal are still stuck where they were before the: -

```
    HandG.setPosition(path[currStep]);
```

See https://github.com/RichardMaher/Brotkrumen/blob/master/HandleMap.js line# 321 for complete example.

How can this possibly be? When can the SRC attribute completely divorce itself from its IMG tag?

This didn't used to happen a few years ago (trust me :-) Has there been some optimization in Chrome? Buffering Map Marker moves? Can I turn this behaviour off?

The "optimize" marker option is set to false. Anyway surely we can just forget Google Maps here, this is just a basic HTML DOM issue right?

***NB:*** PLEASE keep your opinions on the wisdom or otherwise of relying on how Google Maps renders markers. I consider myself suitably chastised and if you have a better way to smoothly transition markers from point to point over a set period of time then please mail me directly. What I'm asking is what witchcraft (my destination marker is a itches hat :-) is at work here.

**Edit 1**

I'll investigate the FF debugging options but am really leaning towards a novel Google Map optimization because the first leg of the trip completes as expected but then my polygon.setPath and my marker.setPosition calls don't take effect progressively. The marker(img) moves after 2 more legs (then on the final leg) and no further path is plotted till the last leg completes.

**Edit 2**

***Please Note***: - The https://github.com/RichardMaher/Brotkrumen repository can be cloned by anyone! Just stick it in a internet facing folder/directory and go for "https://your.domain/TravelManager.html" You'll need a Google Maps API key to use the maps and at least a couple of GPS readings before you can press "Arrive".

Thanks to @Bravo I ran it on FireFox(1) and got a slightly more illuminating response. It does now look like a coding issue (event race condition or some such) as the pattern displayed was: -

- The first leg (as with Chrome) Transitioned from A to B in correct time.
- The second leg was skipped then HandG floated up to the third geolocation position but with what appeared to be a combined duration?
- Likewise, the 4th leg was not visible but the 5th was peachy.
- Unlike Chrome the progressive path was in sync with the marker.

So, yes, it looks like my code is firing 2 events before the browser can give me a Transition and acompanying transitionEnd.

(1) I have work to do on FF asthetic compatibility :-( also (I'm not asking you to teach me FF debug) with Chrome remote USB debugging I get to enter the URL on my PC and it appears in the phone's browser. I can then unplug it, go for a walk around the block, connect it back to the USB again, press "inspect" and have full debug sesion going. On FF I just entered http://localhost:1234 into the phone browser and it activated but I couldn't see how to get a debug session happening.

[image: Screen Capture of debugging session]

Comment: I wouldn't trust the positioning of that tool-tip in chrome - have you tried a different version of chrome? have you tried firefox?

Comment: Can Firefox debug mobile over USB? I will host this on GitHub pages but don't have a internet facing server at the moment. Do you have an example of this happening elsewhere on Chrome? I can assure you that is where (Lat/Lng) the img.src should be and that is also where the transparent DIV Google Maps places on top of the IMG is also residing.

Comment: yes, you can debug firefox on a mobile

Comment: as for example of this happening - not particularly this, but I gave up trying to use chrome developer tools about 10 years ago - I found the tools to be unstable between releases ... something would break, you go back a version and wait for a new release to fix the break - chrome believes their massive user base is fair game for testing changes

Comment: Not just the DevTools unfortunately if happens without them.

Comment: I misunderstood the issue then - so what you're saying is that the HandG image is in the wrong place? It's probably a coding issue then

Comment: @Bravo please see edit 2.

Answer (score -1):

Please feel free to delete the question because, as pointed out by @Bravo, it is a red-herring :-(

The only take-away is: - There are now at least two of us who now strongly recommend using FireFox to debug youre mobile Web Apps and avoid Chrome!

Once I could believe my eyes again, I realized I was getting 2 transitions for my marker reposition. Property Height, Width;

It is with hand on heart that I tell you that several years ago I only got one transition for the multi-property but that's neither here nor there. We are where we are.

Thanks again to https://stackoverflow.com/users/10549313/bravo